# react-collapsible Failed to Compile

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, dependencies, react-component

Im working on spring+reactJS project, currently working on front-end (begginer in this field).

Generally i try to create simple accordion from "REACT-COLLAPSIBLE".

Code is very Simple: JS File:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import '../index.css';
import Collapsible from "react-collapsible/src/Collapsible";


class Author extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (

            <Collapsible trigger="Start here">
                <p>This is the collapsible content. It can be any element or React component you like.</p>
                <p>It can even be another Collapsible component. Check out the next section!</p>
            </Collapsible>

        );
    }

}
export default Author;
```

I have installed *react-collapsible* and i have proper dependency in **package.json**

**When i try to compile this code i have compilation error:**

```
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/react-collapsible/src/Collapsible.js
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (116:8)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|     if (this.props.triggerSibling && typeof 
this.props.triggerSibling === 'string') {
|       return (
|         <span className={`${this.props.classParentString}__trigger- 
sibling`}>{this.props.triggerSibling}</span>
|       )
|     } else if(this.props.triggerSibling) {
```

Certainly this is only a part of project, except this part everything works. I have no idea what should i do, if error is connected with other part of code, which could be useful, let me know.

*Sth is wrong with react-collapsible module? What should i do? When i installed it i didn't receive any WARN, that other dependency should be added*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your import to `import Collapsible from "react-collapsible";`

You are importing from the `src` rather than the `dist` which has been processed.

If you checkout the package.json for this module you will see that the default [exported file](https://github.com/glennflanagan/react-collapsible/blob/2c7ef51e15eb07226847e90e3fdd2d35751d43e1/package.json#L12) is `dist/Collapsible.js`.